# nexus oss or private npm repositroy - how to handle multiple repostiry in npmrc?

Tags: npm, nexus

We are using nexus oss for Team A to serve as npm private registry server.

We have npm-all that is including: npm-proxy (proxy to offical npm) + npm-private

For team A, we have npmrc as:

```
registry=[nexus server repository url/repository/npm-all/]
always-auth=true
//[nexus server repository url]:authToken=xxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Soon, we gonna have team B working on the same project and they have official npm private registry account and token.

For team B, they have npmrc as:
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy

My question is how do I manage to merge two npmrc in this scenario and continue to work flawlessly?

Maybe I should use scope? maybe I should exclude npm-proxy?

I thought about

```
registry=[nexus server repository url/repository/npm-all/]
always-auth=true
//[nexus server repository url]:authToken=xxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
```

Thanks

Comment: Unless you have some need to use registry.npmjs.org you should be able to use the first token, it has access to proxy.  Or alternatively have a second NXRM account with just access to proxy (registry=[nexus server repository url/repository/npm-proxy/]).  I suspect I don't understand your use case, so made this a comment not an answer.